# How to check if ANY are selected

Tags: java

I have a some `JCheckboxes`

```
ap = new JCheckBox("Apple");
ba = new JCheckBox("Banana");
pe = new JCheckBox("Pear");
or = new JCheckBox("Orange");
ma = new JCheckBox("Mango");
```

I want to calculate how many of those are selected, but I am not interested in which exact ones are selected though. How can I achieve this?

Maybe put them in a CheckBox Group then use a `getState()`? not too sure

Answer (score 4):

When you create the checkboxes, you could put the controls in a `List`:

```
ap = new JCheckBox("Apple");
ba = new JCheckBox("Banana");
pe = new JCheckBox("Pear");
or = new JCheckBox("Orange");
ma = new JCheckBox("Mango");

List<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<>();
checkboxes.addAll(Arrays.asList({ap, ba, pe, or, ma}));
```

Then when you want to see how many are checked:

```
int countOfChecked = checkboxes.stream().filter(JCheckBox::isSelected).count();
```

As mentioned by @saka1029 you can omit creating the list of checkboxes by using:

```
int countOfChecked = Stream.of(ap, ba, pe, or, ma).filter(JCheckBox::isSelected).count();
```

Comment: Then if I wanted to write to the action listener, for example if count is 2, do this and this, what would I do? just insert a number to count?

Comment: Add `if (countOfChecked == 2) { doThisAndThis() };`

Comment: Just FYI, if you wanted to check if *any* are selected, you can use `checkboxes.stream().anyMatch(JCheckBox::isSelected)`

Comment: `Stream.of(ap, ba, pe, or, ma).filter(JCheckBox::isSelected).count()`

Comment: @saka1029 Thanks - I have edited to include your solution.

Comment: @Paji.R If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

e. g.

```
int i = (ap.isSelected() ? 1 : 0) + 
        (ba.isSelected() ? 1 : 0) + 
        (pe.isSelected() ? 1 : 0) + 
        (or.isSelected() ? 1 : 0) + 
        (ma.isSelected() ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: yeh something like this. Would this code actually work?

Comment: of course, just try it. Well, maybe you have to put the ternary expressions in parens each, I'm not 100% sure. If you tried, tell me and I will update the answer

Comment: I tested it, with the parentheses around the ternary operators it works. I updated the answer accordingly.